# PHP: date between date

Tags: php, sql, date, between

I have two dates:

```
10-11-2010 and 17-11-2010
```

Now i would like to SELECT all rows with the dates between those two.

How can I do that?

Comment: Are you wanting to select from a database? If so, some table structure information might be useful

Answer (score 10, accepted):

its very simple using `between` in where clause
 , [read more](http://www.webdevelopersnotes.com/tutorials/sql/tutorial_mysql_in_and_between.php3)

```
select * from mytable where date between '10-11-2010' and '17-11-2010'
```

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like a SQL question. [Try the between condition.](http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/between.php)

Answer (score 1):

$datefrom=date('Y-m-d');
$dateto=date('Y-m-d');

$sql = 'select * from mytable where depositdate between $datefrom and $dateto';